# Rails generate not working anymore

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-4

I used to generate models using rails g model , however, i messed up my application and had to do a back-up. since then rails generate doesnt work anymore. The terminal just keeps being busy after i hit enter, instead of being busy for a couple of seconds and then showing the output.

```
^C/home/supervisor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in `gets': Interrupt
```

Things like rails s do work so it seems like there is a problem with the generate command. Any tips or tricks i can perform to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this command     `bin/spring stop`. Run generator command again.